# Jupyter notebook error 'dyld library not loaded: CoreFoundation' after macOS Big Sur update

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook

After updating to macOS Big Sur I get the following error when I run `jupyter notebook`:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
  Reason: image not found
[1]    2971 abort      jupyter notebook
```

Any idea as to how to solve this? I tried re-installing jupyter-notebook using brew (I also updated brew) but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem after upgrading to Big Sur version 11 and nothing worked for me either! i tried brew, install_name_tool, and reinstall jupyter notebook. hope someone can help out!!!

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOSBeta/comments/hfknpa/is_corefoundation_missing_for_everyone_on_big_sur/ `CoreFoundation` is no longer in the working directory. So I do not expect `install_name_tool` would work. Any suggestion?

Comment: I tried using jupyterlab for now and that works... But jupyter notebook is still not working for me...

Comment: It was soooo annoying, but i finally found Visual Studio Code which works nicely in my local system and am using it for now.

Comment: I updated to Big Sur yesterday, but jupyter notebook still works for me. Could my pip versions be of help?: jupyter 1.0.0, jupyter-client 6.1.6, jupyter-console 6.1.0, jupyter-core 4.6.3

Comment: Maybe also try the latest python version? (3.9)

Comment: Same problem with my projects in PyCharm... any solution to this?

Comment: @himty upgrading python3.9 is not helpful for the problem. It is a compatibility issue between Jupyter notebook and Big Sur system directory. Python in terminal and VSC both work out fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem after i upgraded to macOS Big Sur. I updated my python version (3.6.4) to (3.9.0) and after that i just uninstalled the notebook and reinstalled it.
Now it works.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, this finally works for me. I get the control back for my jupyter notebook now. I had some back and forth with conda and python, so ended up with reinstalling anaconda & jupyter notebook, and also had to reset my ipykernel.

Comment: Considering a lot of python modules do not have compatible wheels for python 3.9 yet, i am switching back to python3.8 and Visual Studio Code. For anyone who is considering upgrading Big Sur, DO NOT UPGRADE JUST YET!!!

Comment: Happy that I could help you. Was a big mistake to upgrade to the new os...

Comment: I understand this solves the problem for just jupyter notebook, but like Yolanda Wang said python 3.9 lacks compatibility for now (tensorflow is not supported yet for example). I ended up using anaconda with python3.7.9

Comment: the minimum 3.6 version i could get to work was 3.6.7

Comment: I had trouble using `jupyter` on Big Sur due to a similar macOS-y problem. In my `ipython_kernel_config.py`, I set `c.Kernel._darwin_app_nap = False`, which got `appnope` to stop throwing a different (but similar) macOS-related error and let Jupyter work fine. (Presumably, my computer is now prone to sleeping while a Jupyter server is running; I'm fine with that.)